# Print in real time the result of a bash command launched with subprocess in Python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I'm using the subprocess module to run a bash command. I want to display the result in real time, *including* when there's no new line added, but the output is still modified.

I'm using python 3. My code is running with subprocess, but I'm open to any other module. I have some code that return a generator for every new line added.

```python
import subprocess
import shlex

def run(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip()
        if not line:
            break
        yield line.decode('utf-8')

cmd = 'ls -al'
for l in run(cmd):
     print(l)
```

The problem comes with commands of the form `rsync -P file.txt file2.txt` for example, which shows a progress bar.

For example, we can start by creating a big file in bash:

```sh
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 1000000000 > file.txt
```

Then try to use python to display the rsync command:

```python
cmd = 'rsync -P file.txt file2.txt'
for l in run(cmd):
    print(l)
```

With this code, the progress bar is only printed at the end of the process, but I want to print the progress in real time.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-November/026645.html) you can disable buffering when print in python:

> You can skip buffering for a whole python process using "python -u"
>   (or `#!/usr/bin/env python -u` etc) or by setting the environment
>   variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`.
>
> You could also replace `sys.stdout` with some other stream like wrapper
>   which does a flush after every call.
>
> Something like this (not really tested) might work...but  there are
>   probably problems that could pop up. For instance,  I don't think it
>   will work in IDLE, since sys.stdout is  already replaced with some
>   funny object there which doesn't  like to be flushed. (This could be
>   considered a bug in IDLE  though.)

```
>>> class Unbuffered:
..     def __init__(self, stream):
..         self.stream = stream
..     def write(self, data):
..         self.stream.write(data)
..         self.stream.flush()
..     def __getattr__(self, attr):
..         return getattr(self.stream, attr)
..
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout=Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
>>> print 'Hello'
Hello
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, while -u is certainly useful, I want to display the result of the bash script through python. For example, I want to be able to use the run command inside a jupyter notebook and print the result, or to wait for a specific line to be written to do an action, or to pretty print the result of the bash command.  If I just use -u and (for example), os.system(cmd), I won't be able to do that.